# Windows-Batch Advanced Text Find Function

Tags: batch-file, find, patch

Ok, atm the script I am writing a script that pulls values from several text files but can't seem to find a good way to combine the files into a single text file.

```
FOR /f "tokens=%toknum% delims=:" %%G in ('"find /v /c "" "%~dp0\!systype!Win7Updates.txt""') do set maxcnt=%%G
```

In the text file:

```
KB978601,2010\MS10-019\WinSec-MS10-019-011-P57297-Windows6.1-KB978601-x86.msu,/quiet /norestart
```

I am trying to figure out how to create an area in a file so it will separate the stuff. I want to try and find the title, go to the title and everthing below it will be loaded.

example of what I am trying to do. (also trying to do this in CSV file) So I want the script to find the windows vista patch area and only load the ones below that area. Anyone know if that is possible?

```
:Windows 7 Patches
KB978601,2010\MS10-019\WinSec-MS10-019-011-P57297-Windows6.1-KB978601-x86.msu,/quiet /norestart
KB978601,2010\MS10-019\WinSec-MS10-019-011-P57297-Windows6.1-KB978601-x86.msu,/quiet /norestart
KB978601,2010\MS10-019\WinSec-MS10-019-011-P57297-Windows6.1-KB978601-x86.msu,/quiet /norestart
KB978601,2010\MS10-019\WinSec-MS10-019-011-P57297-Windows6.1-KB978601-x86.msu,/quiet /norestart
KB978601,2010\MS10-019\WinSec-MS10-019-011-P57297-Windows6.1-KB978601-x86.msu,/quiet /norestart

:Windows Vista Patches
KB978601,2010\MS10-019\WinSec-MS10-019-011-P57297-Windows6.1-KB978601-x86.msu,/quiet /norestart
KB978601,2010\MS10-019\WinSec-MS10-019-011-P57297-Windows6.1-KB978601-x86.msu,/quiet /norestart
KB978601,2010\MS10-019\WinSec-MS10-019-011-P57297-Windows6.1-KB978601-x86.msu,/quiet /norestart
KB978601,2010\MS10-019\WinSec-MS10-019-011-P57297-Windows6.1-KB978601-x86.msu,/quiet /norestart
KB978601,2010\MS10-019\WinSec-MS10-019-011-P57297-Windows6.1-KB978601-x86.msu,/quiet /norestart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement "everything below it will be loaded" is not clear. I assume you mean everything below the title up until the next title. I really don't know what you mean by "loaded" - perhaps append those lines to another file? For this solution I will simply echo the lines.

Your test case is pretty lame - the section contents are identical so it is difficult to tell if the code is working properly. Here is a more interesting test case that should be easier to interpret. I've added some `!` characters to illustrate a problem with delayed expansion when using FOR loops.

**test.txt**

```
:Windows 7 patches
Windows 7 line 1!
Windows 7 line 2!
Windows 7 line 3!

:Windows Vista patches
Windows Vista line 1!
Windows Vista line 2!
Windows Vista line 3!

:Windows XP patches
Windows XP line 1!
Windows XP line 2!
Windows XP line 3!
```

Here is a batch script that will echo just the Vista patch section. It toggles delayed expansion on and off within the loop to protect the `!`. The expansion of %%A would not work properly if delayed expansion were on.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=:" %%N in ('findstr /n /c:":Windows Vista patches" test.txt') do set skip=%%N
for /f "skip=%skip% delims=" %%A in (test.txt) do (
  set ln=%%A
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  if "!ln:~0,1!"==":" (endlocal & goto :break)
  endlocal
  echo %%A
)
:break
```

The above solution will strip any blank lines. There are tricks to preserve blank lines if needed. It will also strip any line that begins with `;` because of the default FOR /F "EOL" option. Again there are tricks available to work around this if needed.

Comment: what i meant by "loading" is the first piece of code shows that im getting the switches from the lines, which is how i was loading all the information.

Comment: @user1451070 - Still clear as mud. Your comment says you are "getting the switches from the lines", which I can interpret multiple ways. The code in your question simply counts the number of lines in a text file. I don't see the connection. Try editing your question to show what results you expect.

Comment: the text file has "switches" separated by commas

Comment: @user1451070 - And the code in your question does nothing with the "switches". So I really don't understand what result you are looking for. Please edit your question.